# what is the difference between AIRFLOW_HOME vs AIRFLOW__CORE__AIRFLOW_HOME environment variables

Tags: airflow

Documentation for Airflow https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.9.0/configuration.html

talks about setting an environment variable named $AIRFLOW_HOME which is where airflow will be installed.  The configuration file airflow.cfg is created by this process has an attribute called airflow_home in the [core] section at the top of the file.  This makes sense.

But, the way you override airflow variables in the airflow.cfg with environment variables is with the pattern AIRFLOW__[SECTION]__VARIABLENAME.  Based on that pattern, the airflow home environment variables should technically be managed by the environment variable AIRFLOW__CORE__AIRFLOW_HOME and not AIRFLOW_HOME.

Why the difference?
Are both needed?
is one of them not needed?
do they do different things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do different things insofar that `$AIRFLOW_HOME` works as intended: the value you set will be what you get, and `$AIRFLOW__CORE__AIRFLOW_HOME` is likely to screw things up.

The `$AIRFLOW_HOME` value is special in that it's a prerequisite for a handful of actions and is read without support for the  `$AIRFLOW__[SECTION]__VARIABLENAME` interpolation.